# storybook with ngrx selector and async pipe

Tags: ngrx, storybook

I am using ngrx store to show/hide loading spinner on page. the selectIsLoading selector used to show/hide spinner.

```
export class MainLandingComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    public isLoading$ = this.store.select(selectIsLoading);

}
```

html===

```
div
    class="landing-page"
    id="landing-page"
    [stLoadingMask]="isLoading$ | async"
    [config]="{ message: 'Loading', alignTop: false, fullScreen: true }"
> </div>
```

its working perfectly on live server b ut its breaking when I tried it in storybook with error

*ERROR Error: NG02100: InvalidPipeArgument: 'this.store.select(selectIsLoading)' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'*

stories.ts

```
 export default {
        title: 'Multi Host/Multi Host Landing Page/Stories',
        component: MultiHostLandingComponent,
        decorators: [
            moduleMetadata({
                imports: [MultiHostLandingModule, StorybookCoreModule, CommonModule, StoreModule.forRoot({})],
                providers: [
                    apiInterceptorProvider,
                    provideMockStore({
                        selectors: [
                            {
                                selector: selectIsLoading,
                                value: true
                            }
                        ]
                    })
                ]
            })
        ]
    } as Meta;

/**
 * The main template used for all the stories
 */
const Template: Story<MultiHostLandingComponent> = args => ({ props: { ...args } });
export const LandingWithData = Template.bind({});
```

not sure whats going wrong here

Answer (score 0):

The mocked selector needs to return an observable.

```
 provideMockStore({
                        selectors: [
                            {
                                selector: selectIsLoading,
                                value: of(true)
                            }
                        ]
                    })
```